# Cannot load app onto device

Tags: iphone, xcode, device

I know there are a lot of posts about this, but I cannot get the app to test on my device.  Im wondering about this because I DID get a simple "Hello World" but then it didn't work after that.

I can post screenshots, just request them.  I think I followed all of the provisioning instructions correctly...I double checked.

[image]

I have armv7 changed to armv6 because it is an iPhone 3G.

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Can you put the error log while running application

Comment: thats the thing...there is no error log.  It says "Build successful" and then at the top it says "Finished running App".  There is no error...

Comment: is your device shows into the xcode and did you select it.

Comment: Yes, it shows up.  Would you like a screenshot?

Comment: ya and did you set the proper provision profile and create certificate or not?

Comment: Some times cleaning build/ restarting device/xcode/computer or all of them restart works. Can you please check about that..

Comment: did you change the architectures in the project AND in the target ?

Comment: @NoMoreWishes: I did all of that.
Mutix...ill check.  Pretty sure I did though
EDIT: mutix, Everything is armv6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to add support for iOS 3.0, armv6 in Xcode 4.2 and up:
Set your deployment target to 3.0[image] or earlier:

Modify Architectures to include armv6 like so: 1)Select Other, 
[image]

Click on the "+" button,and Type in "armv6" [image]

Then remove Required Device Capabilities from info.plist by clicking the "-" button [image: in that] row.

Comment: Ill probably get banned for swearing so much, but it was worth it! Thanks

Comment: No problem my friend i can understand that...not a big deal