# Error 0xE803FFE while installing app on iPhone through iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipa

I am trying to install my app on iphone. I dragged the certificates into iTunes libraries. Then I dragged my .ipa file into the libraries. After syncing and installing, it shows the following error:

> The app "XXX" was not installed on the iPhone ... because an unknown error has occured (0xE803FFE)*

Please try to explain the procedure of  installing the app, if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by dragged the certificates? Certificates are used for code -signing. Dragging is generally done with provisioning profiles. Are you able to install the app through XCode?

Comment: No,I'm not able to install it. I dragged the provisioning certificates into the libraries section of iTunes. I think now I almost solved the problem. I'm away from work. Will try on Sunday

Comment: Guys I found the solution. xCode has stopped armv6, so I'm not able to install it.It is perfectly running on armv7 architecture.

Comment: Answer can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9679543/1242357

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. xCode has stopped armv6, so I'm not able to install it.
It is perfectly running on armv7 architecture. Initially I tried to add armv6 in the build settings and also in applications info.plist, but no luck. May be I missed something.

Answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9679543/1242357)

Answer (score 2):

If you are a member of the Apple Developer Program, then go the Members Area and look at the Provision Portal. This tells you everything you need to know to get your app building to a device.

https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action

Comment: They have the tutorial for old version of xCode. Mine is 4.2.What about the error?

Comment: I'm not able to open the link

Comment: You need to sign-in with your apple id you used to sign up to the Developer Program with

Comment: I am running 4.2 and although it is not up-to-date the Provisioning Assistant still works fine and most of it is relevant.

Comment: You might be using armv7 architecture. Now its working for me